# Java Mail API: Find if a mail is forwarded mail or a reply to another mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a very special requirement

I am using Java Mail API to access a user's Inbox. You can say its like a service inbox for complaints. User registers a complaint by sending an email to this address. I fetch every email from Inbox and create a new complaint. My problem is that I don't want to create unnecessary complaints for reply or forwarded emails. Is there a way to find out that.

Answer (score 4):

Most email clients add `Re:` or `Fwd:` to the subject line, but I wouldn't rely on that to determine whether an email is a reply or forwarded text; for example, a German mailclient might put `Betr.:` in front of the original subject.

Instead, you might want to look at the `In-Reply-To:` header and/or the `References:` header. See [RFC 4021](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021) for detailed information on those headers.

You can retrieve the headers from a `Message` by calling the [`getHeader(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Part.html#getHeader(java.lang.String)) method.

Comment: That's really helpful. Now I can identify a reply messages using `References:` header. But I'm not getting something similar for a forwarded message.

Comment: I'm afraid the RFC doesn't dictate a header that should always be present in case of a forwarded email. In that case, maybe subject line parsing is a best-effort approach...

Answer (score 2):

Reading the email header might help, see  http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Part.html#getAllHeaders().  In case of replies, the message header would include:

```
In-Reply-To: Message-ID of the message that this is a reply to
```

In case of a forwarded message, selected headers might be preserved.  Not as straight-forward as the previous case, but it might still be possible to determine if it was a forwarded message.  Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_forwarding#Manual_client-based_forwarding for details.